# Date compare time is AM or PM-Hql query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

In SQL I have a query like this..

```
  SELECT * FROM userdata where date_format(startdate,'%p') = 'AM'
```

How can I change this query to HQL? For a data range I need only morning data.

Comment: i am new to hql.so i am not sure how to deal with this.

Comment: Morning is defined as being between 12AM and 12PM. I would think that the right way to map that entity would be to use a Date type field (TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) on a datetime field in your database. With that in mind the query should be fairly simplistic.

Comment: that field is already timestamp...then how query should be?

Answer (score 0):

`date_format` should work in hql as well. Try the same query in hql.